# Alterar o emmit html:5 ou criar um novo para sempre iniciar com langt=pr-br como padrão

Tags: html, html5, visual-studio-code

Como alterar ou editar o emmit do vsCode que cria uma estrutura html5 básica
"html lang=en" como no exemplo abaixo abaixo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

para sempre iniciar com "html lang=pt-br"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

**Criei e uso esse Snippets, que ajuda na hora de uma criação de página**

**Utilizando já** `<html lang="pt-br">`

Arquivo **.json**

```
{

 "Brazilian": {

    "prefix": "~pt-br",

    "body": [

        "<!-- Snippet Html5 Page em Português -->",

        "<!DOCTYPE html>",

        "<html lang='pt-BR'>",

         "<head>",

            "      <meta charset='UTF-8'>",

            "      <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>",

            "      <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>",

            "      <title>Documento</title>",

        "     </head>",

        "     <body>",

        "     </body>",

         "</html>"
    ],
    "description": "null"
 }
}
```